# Dealing with nested possibly null values in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, lodash, apollo

I am using GraphQL and auto generated types for my queries with Typescript. It tends to create quite a few nested `type | null` types. So I need to do quite long checks for non null values. E.G.

```
            data &&
            data.getCoach &&
            data.getCoach.workouts &&
            data.getCoach.workouts.items &&
            data.getCoach.workouts.items.map((workout) => {/* do something*/});
```

I've tried using lodash `has` helper to check for path existence like

```
has('getCoach.workouts.items', data) &&
data.getCoach.workouts.items.map((workout) => {/* do something*/});
```

but ts compiler doesn't seem to understand this.

Is there better way for checking this apart from making my GraphQL endpoint always return the value?

Comment: have you tried "npm install @types/lodash" ? what is the ts compiler complaining about exactly?

Comment: Yes it's included. Error is that `value is possibly null`

Comment: From quick look the type definition for `lodash/has` is just just accepting the path and object and returns boolean. Which is probably not enough for compiler to understand what's it's doing.

Comment: it will work if you are using `(data as any).getCoach.workouts.items.map(…)`, right?

Comment: It would also work if I disable strict null checks. But I want to keep the type safety here. Doing `(data as any).getCoach.workouts.items.map(…)` would explode in runtime if value is actually `null`

Comment: no, it wouldn't explode since you have `has('getCoach….', data)` before the any casting. If you don't want to do that, you have to fix the interface `data` is implementing.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Misunderstood the answer. But then I'd need to cast my `.items` again right? Will try it later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

Optional chaining has been [released in typescript 3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html)!

You can now do:

```
const items = data?.getCoach?.workouts?.items

items && items.map((v) => {
    console.log(v)
})
```

**Previous answer:**

Just thought I'd mention that [optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) has made it to stage 2 at TC39!

I don't think there are any neat solutions at the moment, so something like jcalz's answer might have to do for now.

Hopefully TS introduces it early like they did with async/await and I can update this answer.

Comment: Nullish coalescing is `??` `?.` is actually called optional chaining.

Comment: Ah good spot, just updated

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript isn't quite powerful enough to represent what you're trying to do.  Ideally, JavaScript and TypeScript would feature a [null-coalescing operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16) and you'd use that. But it doesn't have that.

If you try to strongly type the lodash `has` method, you'll find that the compiler cannot [concatenate string literal types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) or perform [regular expression operations on them](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579), so there's no way for the compiler to take the string `'getCoach.workouts.items'` and understand that `getCoach` will be a key of `data`, and that `workouts` will be a key of `data.getCoach`, etc.

Even without using `has`, it is tricky to represent the sort of nested type manipulation involved here without running into issues with [recursion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897#issuecomment-401418254) of the sort that makes the compiler angry or crashy.

The best I can do is: wrap the object in a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) (requires ES2015 or later) which always has a value at any key you want to use, and you use a special key name (such as `"value"`) to pull out the actual value of the property, or `undefined` if there isn't one.  Here's the implementation:

```
type WrapProperties<T, K extends keyof any> = Record<K, T> & { [P in keyof T]-?: WrapProperties<T[P], K> }

function wrapProperties<T>(val: T): WrapProperties<T, "value">;
function wrapProperties<T, K extends keyof any>(val: T, valueProp: K): WrapProperties<T, K>;
function wrapProperties(val: any, valueProp: keyof any = "value"): WrapProperties<any, any> {
    return new Proxy({}, {
        get: (_, p) => p === valueProp ? val : wrapProperties(
            (typeof val === 'undefined') || (val === null) ? val : val[p], valueProp
        )
    });
}
```

So now, instead of this:

```
if (data && data.getCoach && data.getCoach.workouts && data.getCoach.workouts.items) {
  data.getCoach.workouts.items.map((workout) => {/* do something*/}) 
}
```

You should be able to do this:

```
const wrappedData = wrapProperties(data, "val");    
if (wrappedData.getCoach.workouts.items.value) {
  wrappedData.getCoach.workouts.items.value.map((workout) => {/* do something*/}) 
}
```

I don't know if the implementation is *perfect*; it seems to work when I try it.  As with anything you get from Stack Overflow, your mileage may vary and caveat emptor.  Maybe it will help you.  Good luck!

Comment: I will accept this as an answer. Just will have to wait for feature to be introduced into TS I guess. Will try your solution, but it's a bit over my head....